# Take many value from cookies

Tags: laravel

This is my controller code

```
Cookie::queue('dura', json_encode($subject2), 1000);
```

$subject2 got a value like this from database

```
[{"duraFinal":600},{"duraFinal":1200},{"duraFinal":1200}];
```

How to take 3 of that duraFinal value into variable in blade?

I'm new in laravel, and thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies is already a key-value pair structure in the browser, which means you can only store a `string` to a key of cookies

Maybe try the json_decode them from the string?

```php
$data = json_decode(Cookie::get('dura'));
```

And you can pluck only the values from the decoded object

```php
$result = array_pluck($data, 'duraFinal');
// $result = [600, 1200, 1200];
```